# How to create REST API with optional parameters?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I need to implement an API with these path params.

```
@Path("/job/{param1}/{optional1}/{optional2}/{param2}")
```

Can the second and third params by optional? So the client need not pass these, but have to pass the first and last.

If this is not possible, then is it recommended to rearrange the params in this way?

```
@Path("/job/{param1}/{param2}/{optional1}/{optional2}")
```

How to provide the optional params?

Comment: it's better to rearrange the params, If I had a choice, I would have separated mandatory and optional in 2 sections, separated by a delimiter in URL, then make mandatory as positional, and optional as key value pair, I don't know how, which client, under what scenario you are writing the code, what have you tried till now?

Comment: @abasu I am using JAX-RS. I referred to http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/. Is it required to use regex, or is there any other way?

Comment: How would you distinguish `optional1` and `optional2` in `/job/foo/bar/baz`? What is `bar`?

Comment: I am able to provide optional parameters using the solution provided in www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters. So my issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match the entire path ending in the REST request

```
@Path("/location/{locationId}{path:.*}")
public Response getLocation(
    @PathParam("locationId") int locationId,
    @PathParam("path") String path) {
    //your code
}
```

Now the path variable contain entire path after `location/{locationId}`

You can also use a regular expressions to make the path optional.

```
@Path("/user/{id}{format:(/format/[^/]+?)?}{encoding:(/encoding/[^/]+?)?}")
public Response getUser(
    @PathParam("id") int id,
    @PathParam("format") String format,
    @PathParam("encoding") String encoding) {
    //your code
}
```

Now if you format and encoding will be optional. You do not give any value they will be empty.

Comment: Mind mentioning source? http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/

Answer (score 24):

It might be easier to turn the optional path parameters into query parameters. You can then use `@DefaultValue` if you need it:

```
@GET @Path("/job/{param1}/{param2}")
public Response method(@PathParam("param1") String param1,
    @PathParam("param2") String param2,
    @QueryParam("optional1") String optional1,
    @QueryParam("optional2") @DefaultValue("default") String optional2) {
  ...
}
```

You can then call it using `/job/one/two?optional1=test` passing only the optional parameters you need.

Comment: But if the condition parameter is empty, how to pass this parameter to the sql statement

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the params and try the following:

```
@Path("/job/{param1}/{param2}{optional1 : (/optional1)?}{optional2 : (/optional2)?}")
public Response myMethod(@PathParam("param1") String param1,
                         @PathParam("param2") String param2,
                         @PathParam("optional1") String optional1,
                         @PathParam("optional2") String optional2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make request parameter optional set `@RequestParam` to false in controller class

```
@GetMapping("/get")
public get(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name){
 
/* code of controller......*/

}
```