# Making argument optional in @PathVariable and in @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, boot

I am making a controller which takes two argument as @PathVariable and I want to make second argument optional so I did it like this->

```
@GetMapping(value = {"${URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME}"})
public ResponseEntity<List<CoachRelatedDetails>> getCoachDetailsByCorporateName(@PathVariable String corporateName , @PathVariable(required = false) RoleType roleType){
    System.out.println("ins controller");
    return coachFacade.getCoachDetails(corporateName,roleType);
}
```

where->

```
URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME=/getAllCoachByCorporateName/{corporateName}/{roleType}
```

I added `required = false` in second argument.
but when calling it like this it is giving error : path not found
`http://localhost:8080/getAllCoachByCorporateName/ABC/`

While doing the same thing with @RequestParam I got the same error

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"${URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME}"})
public ResponseEntity<List<CoachRelatedDetails>> getCoachDetailsByCorporateName
                 (@RequestParam String corporateName,
                  @RequestParam(required = false ) RoleType roleType) {
    System.out.println("ins controller");
    return coachFacade.getCoachDetails(corporateName, roleType);
}
```

`http://localhost:8080/getAllCoachByCorporateName?corporateName=ABC`

I found online articles about it , they were doing the same way. I couldn't figure out that where I am going wrong.

Comment: you are confusing `@RequestParam` with `@PathVariable` I think - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know that @PathVariable had a required property, It's not best practice, If you have an optional parameter you should assign it as a request parameter not path variable. so your you path would look like this

`URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME=/getAllCoachByCorporateName`

and your get method would be something like this

```
@GetMapping(value = {"${URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME}"})
public ResponseEntity<List<CoachRelatedDetails>> getCoachDetailsByCorporateName
                 (@RequestParam(required = false ) String corporateName,
                  @RequestParam(required = false ) RoleType roleType) {
    System.out.println("ins controller");
    return coachFacade.getCoachDetails(corporateName, roleType);
}
```

and then your http request would be

> http://localhost:8080/getAllCoachByCorporateName?corporateName=ABC

this should solve your problem, I would also suggest that path to be resource based, so you would change it to /coaches and then pass PathVariables and RequestParams to fetch whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

##### Issue

You had wrong way in PathVariable usage , i could not understand that  why use SpringEL  for Controller URI definition , in most popular scenario ,this way is  unnecssary.
Back to the main topic , May be you are wondering about that Why the `@PathVariable` usage which is in your code  that encounted error .

##### Solution

Just remove `@PathVariable(required = false) RoleType roleType` ,if you try to use `@PathVariable` receive complex data struct  ,there may be some  potential issue like `Serialization/Deserialization`,`URL Encoding`.

As one more suggestion that  use `@RequestBody` receive  complex data struct .

The same principle applies `@RequestParm` ,it is not suit for the  URI like `URL.COACH.GET.ALL.COACH.BY.CORPORATE.NAME=/getAllCoachByCorporateName/{corporateName}/{roleType}` , if you wanna request in this way , just remove the extra uri in tail and the make a request again, it is ok.

##### Appendix

I think that have a reading in [SpringDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web) may be  more helpful for you deepen your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that RoleType is an enum type if yes the u need to create one handler endpoint in the case of **Pathvariable** like below:

```
    @GetMapping(value = {"/testing/{corporateName}"})
    public ResponseEntity<List<CoachRelatedDetails>>getCoachDetailsByCorporateNameOnly(@PathVariable String corporateName) {
        System.out.println("when role type is optional call getCoachDetailsByCorporateNameOnly() ");
        return coachFacade.getCoachDetails(corporateName);
    }
```

[For RequestParam you can refer my answer on this](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715191/how-to-create-rest-api-with-optional-parameters/70119666#70119666)